# Android layout alternative resources

Tags: android, layout, dimensions, screen-size

I have an issue with android layouts. I have different values for dimensions (in dp) for each screen size category `small, normal, large, xlarge` used in my layout, but for some reason my layout still looks way bigger on galaxy s2 compared with xperia s although they both have 4.3 inches. Shouldn't android take care automatically of that? Am I missing something? I think using `sw` will add too much overhead since I'd have many `values-sw` folders.

Comment: What does "layout still looks way bigger" mean? You might consider taking some screenshots and posting them (or uploading them somewhere and linking to them from the question), along with posting the layout file in question.

Comment: I figure the answer when you asked me to take a screenshot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that its not such a big difference (it looked that way because textviews don't split the words at the end of the line) after all, but still there is about 20dp extra space in xperia s width. Which I think its normal for android since the docs say:

> normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp

Answer (score 1):

Have you used sp units for font size for text if yes check the user's font size preferences Is it same on both the devices..you may also need to put resources in different resolution bucket too-mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi..I feel different resolution on both the devices might be causing the issue(I know you have used "dp" but still can try...)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the unit "**sp**" over "*dp*" this will help your view elements to automatically resize as per the screen size and resolution.